# What Languages Need To Create A Space Application Like Stellarium

Tags: planetary-science

I'm Studying 3rd Year Of Computer Science And Engineering. I Planned To Create A Space Application Like Stellarium For Final Year Project. I'm Space Enthusiast.Please Help Me To Choose Which Language Is Best To Create A Space Application.

Comment: a) Wrong site. Your question is about software development. b) Even on StackOverflow the question would be off-topic for provoking opinion-based answers. It depends on so many factors and your question is simply too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much philosophy to this. Pretty much any reasonable high-level language will do. You'd need the language to provide graphics libraries, preferably a 3D graphics, so you can perform the drawing easier, and a database access to keep the catalog of stars, plus basic user interface.

And about every modern programming language provides these. You might consider C#, Java, Python, C++ - you should base your decision upon which you know best and feel most comfortable with, as they all provide the necessary functionality to a very similar degree. You'll likely need to know SQL as well to interact with the database.

Comment: Doing this in Java Swing or something... Haha... AHAHHA... AHAHAHHAAH! 7,000,000 lines of UI code later... Honestly, it's whichever one of those has the best libraries for the job.